# Will I be able to UV map these simple planar shapes in Blender and keep their outer edges straight in the UV map? Something that ZBrush can't do

Tags: uv

I need to UV map these shapes and I normally work with ZBrush, but for this project I need the UV maps of these shapes to have the outer edge of the shape to mimic that of the actual shape, as if you just took the shape and literally unrolled it.

[image: type 1]
[image: shape type 2]
[image: shape typ 3]

ZBrush can not seem to do this as it always curves(distorts) the outer edge of the shape in the UV map. The 2 flattened shapes below are the UV maps from ZBrush of the first two shapes shown.

[image: uv zbrush]
[image: uv 2 zbrush]

So my question is before I start to learn Blender a bit to do this , is it possible? And then will I be able to bring the UV map from Blender to ZBrush and assign it to the shapes in ZBush or just bring in a OBJ of a UV'd mesh of the shape from Blender to ZB and then work on it in there.

Comment: Well I tried it and the answer is yes.